# What is the significance of sensitivity list?

Tags: digital-logic, vhdl, quartus-ii

I implemented BCD counter using JK Flip_Flop. While implementing I missed to add "reset" to the sensitivity list of JK-FlipFlop. Because of that my simulation result appeared like this.

[image]

Later I rectified the problem by adding "reset" to the sensitivity list and I got

[image]

I got output but I am not getting why there was such an error in previous case. If reset is not included also we should get output at very next clock right? In my case it is not happening. Can someone tell me why is it so?

Comment: It would be helpful to post your process, as the sensitivity list is related to the functionality within the process. Also, what are the names of the 4 signals in your simulation output?

Comment: If a process has a sensitivity list, it only runs when an event occurs on a signal in the list. (in simulation. Synthesis tends to ignore sensitivity lists)

Comment: @BrianDrummond What u said is correct. If reset is not there in sensitivity list, process won't run when it changes. But when clock changes, process should run and execute the functionality with new reset value. Right ? But that is not happening in first case.

Comment: Right? Maybe. Process runs and what does it do? At which point I have to refer you to Jeff's comment.

Comment: If the reset is "floating" (not in the list), the output is not predictable.  I suspect that if you run the simulation several times, without the reset defined, you will get different sequences.  Whereas, including  the reset in the list, will produce repeatable sequences.

Answer (score 1):

In this first case, you have a process with sensitivity to the clock and reset lines.

```
process (clk, rst)
if (reset = '1') then
...
else
...
end if;
```

This process like any other process will only update the variables and/or signals inside of it using the given logic every delta time unit in simulation when a member of its sensitivity list has an event. In this case, every time the clock has an event (or a change) or every time the reset has an event. The reset logic above will perform whatever is in the appropriate if/else section (if for active high resets, else for active low resets). Thus, when the clock or reset changes the appropriate if/else section of the logic is performed depending on the state of the reset signal.

```
process (clk)
if (reset = '1') then
...
else
...
end if;
```

So now, if we look at the case where the reset is not a member of the sensitivity list. You are correct in saying that this will no longer be sensitive to changes in the reset but the process is still going to execute the logic inside its block on every clock event, the clock is still in the sensitivity list. Even though your reset is not in the sensitivity list, when your reset has changed the process will realize it during the clock event and execute the reset logic thus, your first case where I assume you don't reset the count.